# Group velocity is zero at zone boundaries

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, velocity, crystals

The E-k diagram derived in Kronig Penney model looks like:
[image]

As we can see that slope of this curve is zero at all zone boundaries as well as k=0, which makes group velocity zero at these points. Why is it so? Why group velocity is zero at these points?

Answer (score 2):

At the boundaries of the Brillouin zone, the wavelength is an integer multiple of the lattice constant. Therefore, strong reflected waves are generated and they are mixed with the traveling wave. Eventually, the waves become standing waves and do not have group velocity.